# Relay-Modern Attempted to update component `Relay(Songs)` that has already been unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay

I'm using found-relay for the routing.

If I don't use fragments and just specify the name in the query then it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

songsContainer.js:

```
import Songs from './component';

export const query = graphql`
  query songsContainerQuery {
    songs {
      ...songsContainer_songs
    }
  }
`;

export default createFragmentContainer(Songs, graphql`
  fragment songsContainer_songs on Song {
    name
  }`,
);
```

component.js:

```
const Songs = ({ songs }) => (
  <Audios
    audios={songs}
  >
    <Song />
  </Audios>
);

export default Songs;
```

routeConfig.js:

```
import Songs, { query as songsQuery } from '../../songs/songsContainer';

export default makeRouteConfig(
  <Route path="/">
    <Route Component={PrimaryLayout}>
      <Route exact path="/" Component={Songs} query={songsQuery} />
    </Route>
  </Route>,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add a [`plural`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-directives.html#relay-plural-boolean) directive or you get this error:

```
graphql`
  fragment songsContainer_songs on Song @relay(plural: true) {
    name
}`
```

Terrible error message, i'll create an issue on relay for the poor error message.